# SwiftUI: How can i present a Popup using Navigation Link

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationlink

I have this code embed in a Navigation View and i want RankingUserDetail presented as a Pop-up, i've tried changing the size of the View, using View.popOver style and looking for the presenting methods, can't figure out. 
Already tried to change the frame of view also, but it keeps resizing to fit device screen.
Thanks for the attention

```
 List(UsersList.users){ value in
            NavigationLink(destination:
            RankingUserDetail(user: value)){
                RankingViewRow(user: value,rowNumber: self.UsersList.users.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == value.id})!,needAppearance: 0).frame(width: 343, height: 116)
            }
        }
```